# pass array with ajax to server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to pass ids as array via ajax but when I dump out the get variable on server side with PHP I do not get any values, the array is empty. Debugging with firebug I see that the array is getting passed but `[]` is encoded `ids%5B%5D`

**my javascript**

```
  function update_category(selected) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/?controller=products&action=update_category',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "application/JSON",
            data: {
                ids: cat_ids,
                s_category: selected
            },
            success: function(data) {
                addAlert('alert-'+data, data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                addAlert('alert-'+data.responseText, data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

var_dump `$_GET['ids']` null dumping the hole `$_GET` I get  ["ids%5B%5D"]

I do not understand why the array is getting encoded on submit in linux environment

Under ubuntu 12.10 PHP 5.3.10 Firebug XHR->PARAMS

```
  action    update_category
    controller  products
    ids%5B%5D   1403172219
    ids%5B%5D   1530542001
    s_category  1
```

how to pass properly the array?

Comment: The $_GET['ids] will give a parse error. But try doing a post instead of a get.

Comment: did you set the js variable cat_ids to something?  it looks null in your function so it would pass null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already passing GET values int he URL here:

> /admin/**?controller=products&action=update_category**

Then the information in `data` probably never passes.

Try this instead:

```
  function update_category(selected) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "application/JSON",
            data: {
                ids: cat_ids,
                s_category: selected,
                controller: 'products',
                action: 'update_category'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                addAlert('alert-'+data, data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                addAlert('alert-'+data.responseText, data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: the same. What is interesting that on my localhost under xampp I do not face this problem, but on live ubuntu server dos not work